# Extracting data using web_reg_save_param_regxp

Tags: loadrunner

I am trying to extract multiple values from a web content.I tried using the web_reg_save_param_regexp() function to extract data but would getting the error, Check whether the requested regular expression exists in the response data

Text i am trying to extract All 3 test-ids that satisfies class="success apply token: 
class="success apply token" test-id="12345678" test-id2="NAME-007" test-id-3="732843734"

web_reg_save_param_regexp(
        "ParamName=Test",
        "RegExp=class=\"success\apply\token\""test-id=\"12345678\""test-id2=\"NAME-007\""test-id-3=\"732843734\"",
        "Ordinal=ALL",
        SEARCH_FILTERS,
        LAST);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp(“ParamName=C_testId_1”,
“RegExp=class=\"success apply token: class=\"success apply token\" test-id=\"([0-9]+)\" test-id2=\"([A-Z-0-9])\" test-id-3=\"([0-9]+)\"”,
"Group=1",
"Ordinal=ALL",
LAST);

web_reg_save_param_regexp(“ParamName=C_testId_2”,
“RegExp=class=\"success apply token: class=\"success apply token\" test-id=\"([0-9]+)\" test-id2=\"([A-Z-0-9])\" test-id-3=\"([0-9]+)\"”,
"Group=2",
"Ordinal=ALL",
LAST);

web_reg_save_param_regexp(“ParamName=C_testId_3”,
“RegExp=class=\"success apply token: class=\"success apply token\" test-id=\"([0-9]+)\" test-id2=\"([A-Z-0-9])\" test-id-3=\"([0-9]+)\"”,
"Group=3",
"Ordinal=ALL",
LAST);
```